# C# - Keep program running after catch and convert int in method to float?

Tags: c#

I just recently started programming and am trying to work through a code that doesn't quite agree with me.

My main problems are:

1. After the catch is activated, I'd like for the program to run again, so that new numbers can be typed in, but instead right now it's simply closing it.
2. I'd like the FahrenheitToCelsius to convert into float, while being inserted as an int first.

I've tried many different options from similar questions I found here but right now I've reached a stand still since none of it seemed to work in my code (Probably because I'm not seeing the whole picture yet).

Here's my code so far, without all the failed attempts in it to make it easier to overlook.

```
class Program
{

    //METHOD: CONVERTS FAHRENHEIT TO CELSIUS
    public static int FahrenheitToCelsius (int fahrenheit)
    {
        int celsius = ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9;
        return celsius;
    }


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //===============INTRO AND METHOD CALLING============
            Console.WriteLine("Skriv in temperaturen i Fahrenheit: "); 
            int fahrenheit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
            int cel = FahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit); 



            //==============-NOT ACCEPTABLE TEMPERATURES==============
            do

                //ABOVE ACCEPTABLE TEMP
                if (cel > 77)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This is too hot. Turn down the temperature.");
                    int cel3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    cel = FahrenheitToCelsius(cel3);


                }

                //BELOW ACCEPTABLE TEMPERATURE
                else if (cel < 73)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This is too cold. Turn up the temperature");
                    int cel2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    cel = FahrenheitToCelsius(cel2);
                }


            while (cel < 73 || cel > 77);



            //================ACCEPTABLE TEMPS===================

            //Acceptable but not perfect temp
            if (cel == 73 || cel == 74 || cel == 76 || cel == 77)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Acceptable temperature.");
            }

            //PERFECT TEMPERATURE
            else if (cel == 75)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Perfect temperature!");
            }
        }

        //================EXCEPTION=================
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error. Only numbers acceptable.");

        }

            Console.ReadKey();
    }   
}
```

}

As I said, I'm super new to programming so the answer is probably right in front of me, but after twelve hours of trying on these two problems alone, I think I need some help!

Comment: As invalid user input is expected you should be handling that at input and not using exceptions. Be easier to control the loop too. If this is for an exercise requiring try/catch then find out the actual exception you wish to handle. It is bad practice to catch Exception generally.

Comment: You already know what a loop looks like.  Just use another loop around Console.ReadLine().  Keep looping until int.TryParse() returns *true*.

Comment: Don't just do `catch (Exception)` - if you know the exception then do that - which, in this case, is `FormatException`. But better yet, don't use exceptions for this. Bad user input isn't exeptional - it's normal. Use `TryParse` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a float instead of an int, you can use `float.Parse()` instead of `int.Parse`.

If you want to continue the flow on invalid input, you could use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`, something like this:

```
float fahrenheit = 0;
float cel;
while (fahrenheit == 0)
{
    if (float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out farhenheit)
        cel = fahrenheit;  
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Error. Only numbers acceptable.");
}
```

Comment: @DmitryBychenko good question, but the Original used these separate variables, so I included them. There are several variables that could be optimized away in the code, but that would be a different question alltogether.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Stack Overflow )

Adding method that validates input values will help you here

```
private static int GetUserInput()
{
  while (true)
  {
    int outputValue;
    Console.WriteLine("Skriv in temperaturen i Fahrenheit: ");

    var inputValue = Console.ReadLine();

    var userInputIsInteger = int.TryParse(inputValue, out outputValue);

    if (!userInputIsInteger)
       {
         Console.WritLine("Only integer values can be accepted as input");
       }

    if (userInputIsInteger || inputValue == "q") // in user type Q he wants to exit an app
    {
      return outputValue;
    }
  }
}
```

and then use it here

```
    //===============INTRO AND METHOD CALLING============
    var fahrenheit = GetUserInput();
    int cel = FahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit);
```

Might even remove try catch from you code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static int Ask(string message)
{
    int result = -1;
    bool valid = false;
    while (!valid)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        valid = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int cel = -1;

    while (cel < 73 || cel > 77)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        int fahrenheit = Ask("Skriv in temperaturen i Fahrenheit: ");
        cel = FahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit);
        if (cel > 77)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is too hot. Turn down the temperature.");
        }
        else if (cel < 73)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is too cold. Turn up the temperature");
        }
    }

    if (cel == 75)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Perfect temperature!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Acceptable temperature.");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, do not cram all the matter into a single `Main`, *extract methods*:

```
   private static float FahrenheitToCelsius(float t) {
     return (t - 32.0f) / 5.0f * 9.0f ;
   }

   private staic float ObtainFarenheight() {
     while (true) {
       Console.WriteLine("Skriv in temperaturen i Fahrenheit: "); 

       float result = 0.0f;

       if (float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
         return result; 

       Console.WriteLine("Error. Only numbers acceptable.");
     } 
   }

   private static float AcceptableCelsius() {
     while (true) {
       float result = FahrenheitToCelsius(ObtainFarenheight());

       if (result > 77) 
         Console.WriteLine("This is too hot. Turn down the temperature.") 
       else if (result < 73) 
         Console.WriteLine("This is too cold. Turn up the temperature"); 
       else 
         return result;
     }
   }
```

And you'll have

```
   public static void Main(string[] args) {
     float cel = AcceptableCelsius();

     //DONE: please, notice that perfect temperatures is a range, not a set
     if (cel > 74.5 && cel < 75.5) 
       Console.WriteLine("Perfect temperature!");
     else 
       Console.WriteLine("Acceptable temperature.");

     Console.ReadKey();
   }
```

Footnote: I'd rather used `double` (it's more convenient - at least not `f` suffixes) when working with temperatures, but `float` is OK as well.